# how do i edit the useragent in python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

The python requests library already sets the useragent name as "Python Requests" and major and minor version. I want to keep this and not overwrite it, but I want to add/change the "platform" field.

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have to overwrite the whole thing and manually have to enter the useragent name and version I just want to insert my own platform info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal browser sends following: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)

So I think you need next, you can update platform format with anything you needed.

```
import requests
import platform

url = 'http://localhost/i.php'

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
default_agent = headers['User-Agent']

headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': default_agent + ' (' + platform.platform() + ')',
    }
)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print response.content
```

output:

```
python-requests/2.12.4 (Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1)
```

i.php is a server side, you can use any perfered to test the client.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```